# How to use Time Profiler Instrument with iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, optimization, time, profiler, instruments

I'm trying to get Time Profiler to play nice with me. I am able to set it up with my iPhone and capture data. However, Instruments doesn't really show much information about where the virtual bottlenecks exist in my code. If I click on the memory addresses to show more detail Instruments tells me that they're unavailable.

How can I get the info I need to optimize my code?

Screenshot:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/4ikah2/3]

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2rffvh5/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow uh... I got it to work... You need to set a target by clicking the info icon next to your iPhone's icon..

[image: Setting the Time Profiler Instrument's target process]